# How to become a cricket umpire for icc?

Tags: cricket, officiating, international-sports

I like cricket very much, is there a way to take umpire as carrier?
If so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are living in Europe you can find this [ICC Europe Umpire Education Courses](http://www.icc-europe.org/education/uec.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to take umpiring as a career BUT it is very difficult to get to the level at which it is a proffessional option and it takes a lot of time.

The first step in getting involved in umpiring is to contact your local cricket association and ask about umpire training.  They will offer some, in the UK it's the ECB ACO, in europe its ICC Europe, I am fairly sure the BCCI and PCB also offer the same.

Then it is a matter of getting out on the field and umpiring and over time if you have the abilities needed you will rise towards the top and may eventually be able to do it as a career.

However given the competition it will take time and luck.

There are for example only 12 elite umpires employed by ICC.

The ECB employees a further 33 on its 1st class and reserve lists.

Ben